# How will the US version of the Google Pixel perform in Germany?

Tags: nexus-5, hardware, google

I am a very happy Nexus 5 owner in general. However, I have noticed that my (US version) Nexus 5 does not offer LTE in Germany --- at least on Tchibo as a carrier, who resells o2 (and maybe E-Plus, I am not sure). Now I am wondering whether the (unlocked) US version of the Google Pixel will have the same problem.

[GSM arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel-8346.php) has some specs for the supported bands:

> **2G bands**
>
> GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900   CDMA 800 / 1900
>
> **3G bands**
>
> HSDPA 850 / 1700(AWS) / 1900 / 2100 - USA
>
> HSDPA 800 / 850 / 900 / 1700(AWS) / 1900 / 2100 - Global
>
> CDMA2000 1xEV-DO
>
> **4G bands**
>
> LTE band 1(2100), 2(1900), 3(1800), 4(1700/2100), 5(850), 7(2600), 8(900),
>   12(700), 13(700), 17(700), 18(800), 19(800), 20(800), 21(1500),
>   26(850), 28(700), 32(1500), 38(2600), 39(1900), 40(2300), 41(2500) -
>   Global
>
> LTE band 1(2100), 2(1900), 3(1800), 4(1700/2100), 5(850),
>   7(2600), 8(900), 12(700), 13(700), 17(700), 20(800), 25(1900),
>   26(850), 28(700), 29(700), 30(2300), 41(2500) - USA

Yet I feel unable to judge the significance of the differences, especially in terms of which bands carriers may be deciding to use in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know EU carriers use Band 20 and Band 3/7 in conjunction, one to cover the densely populated areas and another to cover the rural places. This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks_in_Europe) mostly supports my knowledge. Since the US variant has 3+7+20, it should work alright.

P.S. Are you buying from US to avoid the huge price bump in buying the global variant outright?

Comment: "Are you buying from US to avoid the huge price bump in buying the global variant outright?" - Yes.

Comment: Guessed so. Pixel is so inflated in price (even the US one). As a N6P owner I feel lucky that it isn't a Nexus and I haven't had to swap my phone this year.

Comment: My US Nexus 5 is lacking support for LTE bands 3, 7 and 20 altogether, which may explain why LTE was not working. This does not add much information, but it does not contradict your statement either.